# what will be the output of the following code related to pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, vector

for the following code, what should be displayed on the screen?

```
int num = 125;
int *numPtr ; numPtr = &num;
cout << numPtr << ’\t ’ << *numPtr;
```

the options:
A. memory address of variable numPtr, followed by a tab, followed by 125 
B. memory address of variable num, followed by a tab, followed by 125
C. value of num in hexadecimal followed by a tab followed by 125
D. memory address of variable numPtr followed by a tab followed by NULL

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Try and predict for yourself and then see if you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it for a minute:

you create an int called num with the value 125

`int num = 125;`

You then creates a pointer numPtr ( remember pointers are only a memory address ) that has to point to an int.

`int *numPtr;`

You then take the memory address of num ( that is what the address-of operator (`&`) means, "take the memory address"), and put it in numPtr, so numPtr now contains the address of num.

`numPtr = &num;`

If you now only output `std::cout << numPtr` you will get the memory address, and to fetch the value at that location you type `*numPtr`

With this information, I think you should be able to understand what is happening. Good luck with the test.